# Change background-color in two different divs on one hover

Tags: html, css

I dont know how to ask this properly, but i will try to do that. I have tons of absolute divs. All divs with different classes. When i hover one div, i need to change `background-color`to that hovered div, also at same time, another div should be hovered even if that element is not hovered. What i ment, is that i need to change both divs background color on hover in one hover.

**css**

```
.button1 { position:absolute; left:10px; top:10%; width:10%; height:10%; background:red; }
.button2 { position:absolute; left:10px; top:25%; width:10%; height:10%; background:blue; }

.button1:hover { background:green; }
.button2:hover { background:green; } 

etc //
```

**html**

```
<div class="button1"></div>
<div class="button2"></div>

etc //
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmammLoe/1/)

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
.button1:hover + .button2 { background:green; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmammLoe/3/)

Or, if the buttons don't immediately follow one another (but still follow, as a sibling), you can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```
.button1:hover ~ .button2 { background:green; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmammLoe/5/)

---

If you require both buttons to be hovered, you would need to have a container over which you could hover and in turn, change descendants' styles:

```
.container:hover > div { background:green; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmammLoe/7/)

Comment: I like this a lot! But it doesn't work if the second button is hovered.

Comment: @Type-Style There is no way of targeting a previous element using CSS selectors.

Comment: @Tauras Glad to have helped.

Comment: the last solution has best browser support, as the sibbling selector (~) was introduced with css3 (for support see: http://caniuse.com/#search=selector). the first solution has sufficient support too, but works only for the first following element

Comment: @George, i have one question. If i am using reverse ``.button1:hover ~ .button2 { background:green; }`` , i mean: ``.button2:hover ~ .button1 ..`` , why it does not work properly?

Comment: @Tauras As I said earlier, *'There is no way of targeting a previous element using CSS selectors'*

Answer (score 1):

Alter your css.

**Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmammLoe/8/)**

**The HTML**

```
<div class="button1"></div>
<div class="button2"></div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.button1 { position:absolute; left:10px; top:10%; width:10%; height:10%; background:red; }

.button2 { position:absolute; left:10px; top:25%; width:10%; height:10%; background:blue; }

.button1:hover { background:green; }
.button1:hover + .button2 { background:green; }
```